# How do i compare php object element of type bool

Tags: php, object

I have a PHP object with an element of type bool but if I compare it to `== true` or `== 1` or anything it doesn't match, if I also dump it out it returns an empty string but if I run `is_bool()` on it I get true. So PHP knows the element is a boolean but for some reason I can't compare it?

```
var_dump($obj);

object(stdClass)#1628 (33) {
    ["BoolElement"]=>
    bool(true)
}

echo is_bool($obj->BoolElement); // true
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you doing exactly? You don't need to compare it with anything if you just want to check the value: `if ($obj->BoolElement) {}`

Comment: You literally wrote `if ($obj->BoolElement == true)` and that didn't work?

Comment: yep i did == and === and it doesn't match. I'm using PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 with Suhosin-Patch

Comment: Show the code that is failing.

Comment: Your echo doesnt tell you what you think it does there

Comment: can you clarify hanky ? the is_bool is stating that the element type is a boolean right ?

Comment: jeroen, im doing a simple if ($obj->BoolElement == true) it never falls inside

Comment: Works for me: http://www.tehplayground.com/#dxdKKfAAf

Comment: Did you use `== 'true' ` or `== true `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `===`

This compares the type, so it should work more strictly.

Comment: the problem was between the chair and the keyboard! thanks for your help